# What is the simplest possible way to grab an email address from the PHP Google API

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I have a valid access token for a user who has logged into my website using their Google ID and I have been able to grab their name and avatar by using:

```
$client->setAccessToken($response);
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
$me = $plus->people->get("me");

var_dump($me);
```

however that doesn't give me their email. So I try this:

```
$plus2 = new Google_Oauth2($client);
$email = $plus2->getuserinfo("me");
var_dump($email);
```

and it doesn't work. It says that Google_Oauth2 isn't a class, which makes sense, cause I'm basically guessing, but what would actually work? There's a lot of conflicting advice on SO, maybe the google api has changed, but what would be the very bare minimum amount of code that would get me their email address?

Comment: What scopes are you asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the Plus API, just call `$oauth2->userinfo->get()` to get an associative array of attributes which will include the email address. Example:

```
$oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);
$userinfo = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
var_dump($userinfo);

echo "Email is: {$userinfo['email']}\n";
```